# concatenate mt_rand or large mt_rand

Tags: php, random

I have code like this

```
var_dump(randomDigits(20));
function randomDigits($numDigits) {
    if ($numDigits <= 0) {
        return '';
    }

    return mt_rand(0, 9) . randomDigits($numDigits - 1);
}

echo "<br />";

var_dump(randomDigits2(20));
function randomDigits2($numDigits) {
    if ($numDigits <= 0) {
        return '';
    }

    return mt_rand(1000, 9999) . randomDigits($numDigits - 4);
}

var_dump(randomDigits3(20));
function randomDigits3($numDigits) {
    $digits = '';

    for ($i = 0; $i < $numDigits; ++$i) {
        $digits .= mt_rand(0, 9);
    }

    return $digits;
}
```

all 3 functions generate 20 digits. but which would you choose and why? if none of these two are good, please give an example? thanks in advance

Comment: Neither - why use recursion when a simple loop would be more efficient

Comment: @MarkBaker, question updated. so third method is better? or do you have any good example generating random number?

Comment: Third is definitely better. Second won't work if $numDigits isn't a multiple of 4; and for both 1 and 2, recursion is an expensive overhead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd go for a loop, keep it simple

```
<?php

function random_number($length = 20)
{
    $number = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) $number .= mt_rand(0,9);
    return $number;
}

echo random_number();
```